# BehaveN - passing argument with string type from txt scenario

Tags: bdd

[Playing around with BehaveN](http://code.google.com/p/behaven/)

This is my scenario

> Given a new calculator
>   When adding "2"
>   Then the result is 1

Problem is with `When` part, it receives null as argument.

```
public void when_adding_x1(string x1)
{
    //x1 == null :(
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took source from git and it works now...